# Forbidding illegal file and folder characters in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, file, directory, naming, illegal-characters

We all know to avoid certain characters when naming files and folders. But, in a Mac OS X server environment with Mac and PC clients, this is not so simple. Apple allows certain characters that just don't play well with PC's. The biggest problem is the "/" character, which on a PC denotes a directory change.

Mac OS X forbids the use of the ":" character. My question is, is there a way to expand upon this via Terminal and not allow certain other characters, or substituting another character when an illegal character is entered. So, if I enter a file or folder name of "Test 4/20/17", the system will automatically change it to "Test 4-20-17"?

Comment: To clarify, you're asking if MacOS has some function that knows all the illegal characters in *other* operating systems?

Comment: No, I'm asking if there may be a Terminal command available that can alter the OS to not accept certain characters, just like it does with the colon character.

Comment: Doubtful.  `/` at the Aqua layer is converted to `:` at the Darwin layer, anyway.